# TCP vs UDP Error-Checking

Tags: connection, tcp, sockets, udp

I've bounced upon two articles that describe in-depth on how TCP and UDP connections work. However there is some kind of inconsistency. Where one article tells me that UDP does no Error-Checking at all, the other article mentions that UDP Does some sorth of error-checking but no recovery or corrections. I would like to know which of the two is the most correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

UDP has **optional** error **detection**:

- **Optional**: UDP supports checksums, which the receiver can use to detect errors. However, the use of checksums is optional.
- **Detection**: There is no built-in recovery mechanism in UDP. This task is left to the application using UDP.

The Wikipedia articles on [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) and [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) are good starting points for more information. Look at the segment/datagram header formats and see how checksums are handled.